# Eloquent recursive relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an issue where I'm trying to get all descendants of an object and keep only those with a specific property.

I have these relations:

```php
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function allChildren()
    {
        return $this->getChildren()->with('allChildren');
    }
```

And I get this type of array for example:

```php
$array = [
           0 => ['name' => 'aaa', 'type' => 0, 'parent' => null, 'children' => [
                 1 => ['name' => 'bbb', 'type' => 1, 'parent' => null, 'children' => []], 
                 2 => ['name' => 'ccc', 'type' => 0, 'parent' => null, 'children' => [
                       3 => ['name' => 'ddd', 'type' => 1, 'parent' => 2, 'children' => []]
                        ]]
                    ]],
           4 => ['name' => 'eee', 'type' => 0, 'parent' => null, 'children' => []]
];
```

For this example, I would like to remove all objects that are of `type 1` and get a clean array without those only.

I don't really understand why it is possible to get all descendats of an object but not be able to pass conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `collapse()` and `filter()` might be usable for this, but otherwise you're likely going to need some logic on your relationships to filter them by `type`, like `hasMany()->where("type", 1)`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if collapse or filter are useful to this case. Whereas relationship condition would help me, it simply does not work. I dont know why.
`$this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->where('type','<>',1);` but I guess it's because of the recursive function.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the ids of each row? The two elements of the outer array have index 0 and 4 respectivly, does it matter to keep these as they are?

Comment: actually it's an eloquent object (a collection) that I transform into an array. Should I not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection only solution would be something like this (place the custom macro in a Service Provider of your application):

```php
Collection::macro('whereDeep', function ($column, $operator, $value, $nested) {
    return $this->where($column, $operator, $value)->map(function ($x) use ($column, $operator, $value, $nested) {
        return $x->put($nested, $x->get($nested)->whereDeep($column, $operator, $value, $nested));
    });
});
```

Then where needed call:

```php
$yourArray->whereDeep('type', '!=', 1, 'children');
```

On your example, the macro works like this:

1. Filter all the elements where: `type != 1`
   (the outer array will beuntouched as both items has `type => 0`)
2. For each element of the current array:

   - Retrive the `children` property and apply the same filtering to this subarray starting with the first point of this instructions.
   - Replace the `children` property with the new children property just filtered.

Anyways, you should try to deep dive into why the relation filtering doesn't work. That solution would be more efficient if optimized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution where there is no need of all this recursion or any of these relationship calls so I share it:

Using: ["gazsp/baum"](https://github.com/gazsp/baum)

```php
// get your object with roots method

$contents = Content::roots()->get();

// and simply run through the object and get whatever you need 
// thanks to getDescendantsAndSelf method

$myArray = [];

foreach($contents as $content) {
 $myArray[] = $content->getDescendantsAndSelf()->where('type', '!=', 1)->toHierarchy();
}

return $myArray;
```

This works for me the same way as the other method above.